# How to check if the JSON is correctly receives

Tags: php, json, ajax

I'm sending a JSON with the POST AJAX method to a PHP file and I would like to know how can I check if the JSON is correctly sent before using the `json_decode` function ?

The `isset($_POST['myJSON'])` and `!empty($_POST['myJSON'])` functions are they correct for this case or I cannot use them because my variable is a JSON?

Comment: Its correct. With **isset($_POST['myJSON']) ** you check if myJSON key is set regardless of data type.

Comment: why you want to check if your json is ok before?
 the json_decode return null if your json failed.. `if(isset($_POST['myJSON'])){ $var = json_decode($_POST['myJSON']); if($var == null){ // something wrong? }}` ?

Comment: Because when I learned the base of PHP, for the case of a form, I learned to first check if a variable exists and if it's not empty to use it after. So I was thinking, in the case of a JSON that I should make some tests

Answer (score 1):

You can check by using JavaScript function `JSON.parse($val)` before sending to php file

If it shows error then your json is not correct